# C# Sharing file handles across threads

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code that is executed by `n` threads. The code contains,

```
for(;;)//repeat about 10,000 times
{
    lock(padlock)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(fileName, text);
    }
}
```

Basically, all threads write to the same set of 10,000 files and hence the files are the shared resource. The issue is that the 10,000 open,write,close performed by each thread is slowing down my program considerably. If I could share the file handlers across threads, I'd be able to keep them open and write from different threads. Can someone throw some light on how I can proceed?

Comment: You want to keep 10.000 files open at the same time? Please elaborate.

Comment: If it speeds up my system, yes?

Comment: lol..can u suggest some alternative

Comment: When you say "slowing down my program", what are you comparing it against? "slowing down" is a relative term. Also, how slow does it run, ie. to process those 10.000 files, how long does that take?

Comment: Can you restructure the program so that it processes the files one at a time instead of jumping back and forth between them? That would reduce the number of open/close cycles you need to perform.

Comment: Comparing it against my expectations? There is a good 7 minutes between the first file written and the last file written. I cannot restructure my program. This is how it works

Comment: Does the sepcs really say "read/write these 10.000 files in different threads" or didn't you mean that the program couldn't be restructured?
Locking and waiting for a lock takes time. potentially a lot of it. Since you could end up with sequential processing even tho you use multiple threads. rewritting so you don't need the lock would give you a faster solution

Comment: Restructuring the program could be difficult. I just thought using threads would make a difference, but you're right. the time difference is not significant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let all threads write to a syncronised list. 
Let one thread 'eat' the items on the list and write them with a single FileWriter to the file.

Presto problem solved in exchange for some extra memory usage.

Comment: aren't there a lot of issues with thread safety of collections?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you open the file using a `FileStream` and share that instead of the `fileName`.