# Management and control threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

This code(sorry for this horrible code):

```
int count = 0;
while (true)
{
    if (count < 3)
    {
        try
        {
            ac = acci.Pop();
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }
        if (ac != "")
        {
            ++count;
            new Thread(delegate() 
                       {
                         Console.WriteLine("Run " + ac.Name);
                         Go(ac);
                         --count;
                       }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

In Go() i'm using WebClient. When i'm running it, same thread running more 1 times, but this it shouldn't happen.
ac - String, count - Int, In Go() Webclient download page, parse some tags and save tags values in file. Need to run just 3 threads at the same time.

Comment: @harungo - it's not very clear what the problem is or what you want it to do instead.  Can you try to retype the issue out so it's a little clearer?

Comment: I know that.. I was being sarcastic by his bold statement.

Comment: What ac is ? In one place  you compare it with string in other you use property Name over it.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that you're decrementing count and thereby undoing the increment you previously did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest change I see is just change the definition of count:

```
volatile int count = 0;
```

This makes the different threads all use the same 'int' variable, whereas without it they may have different copies.

However, you need more changes than that, I think.  Int's aren't meant for thread synchronization.  That's what semaphores are for:

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(3,3);
while (acci.Count > 0)
{
     ac = acci.Pop();
     if (ac != "")
     {
         new Thread(delegate() 
                   {
                     sem.WaitOne();
                     Console.WriteLine("Run " + ac.Name);
                     Go(ac);
                     sem.Release();
                   }).Start();
     }
}
```

BE CAREFUL THOUGH!!!  We can create a lot of threads there!  If your system can get a lot of requests at once you may want to move the WaitOne outside of the new Thread(...).

You may also want to look at the ThreadPool class and the BackgroundWorker class, depending on your environment.

Comment: Question: how use write stream in this threads(write in same file)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104393/c-sharp-sharing-file-handles-across-threads

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your ac thing is, but you have while(true) {} which is an infinite loop.  It only breaks on an exception with your ac variable assignment.  This is BAD.  Do NOT use try/catch to implement application logic.  generating an exception is a BIG deal for your code.  You should use if/else statements for this sort of thing.  For example

```
if (acci.length == 0)
{
    break;
}
else
{
    ac = acci.Pop();
}
```

that said, I have no clude what you're trying to do here, but multithreading is DANGEROUS.  Even if your count is assigned correctly, there are risks that your threads will do wierd things.

Comment: The variable "acci" is Stack, he not support Length.

Comment: A lot of things have a TryPop() or Peek() or something, too.  There's always a way to tell if there's something to pop, though.